# Replacing similar items of an array from the objects value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

There's an object below named cricket mania consisting of net runs and points scored by different countries. I am trying to write a code in JS to sort the teams according to their Points first, and if they have the same points, use Net Run as the
tiebreaker. In our case, its the Bangladesh and Nepal that has scored same points, so we will be considering the net runs of those two countries which are -1.176 of Bangladesh and -0.849 of Nepal. Since Nepal has got the highest net runs, we will arrange Nepal's net runs first.  I have sorted the points but I am unable to figure out how do I replace the similar points by using net runs. I need the below  array to be logged in to the console
[ '3', '4', '5', '6', '-0.849', '-1.176' ].I would surely appreciate the time the people of this community would take to solve this little doubt that I am stucked in and would be more than happy to have someone to aid me out in this process of learning :)

[This is the link to my codepen](https://codepen.io/suha_ain77/pen/OJEWowp?editors=0010)

``

```
    const cricketMania = {
    India: {
        netRuns: "1.319",
        points: "8"
    },
    Pakistan: {
        netRuns: "1.028",
        points: "6"
    },
    Saudi: {
        netRuns: "0.874",
        points: "5"
    },
    Nepal: {
        netRuns: "-0.849",
        points: "4"
    },
    Bangladesh: {
        netRuns: "-1.176",
        points: "4"
    },
    Zimbabwe: {
        netRuns: "-1.138",
        points: "3"
    }
};

var point = []; // [ '8', '6', '5', '8', '4', '3' ]
for (let m in cricketMania) {
    point.push(cricketMania[m]["points"]);
}

var sortedpoints = point.sort((a, b) => a - b);
document.write(sortedpoints); //[ '3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '8' ]
```

``

Comment: Please take some time to make your requirements and code clearer. The comments in your code don't match the actual values produced by the code. And since Bangladesh and Nepal have a value of 4, it doesn't make sense to put their net runs at the end of the array (after higher-scoring teams). Also, the requirement you've given for desired output will only give you numbers, where presumably you want to have the entire teams' data sorted, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the shortest possible solution, but it might give the point.

1. We convert the objects to an array which contains name of the country and other values.
2. Then we sort array by points and then by netRuns (if points are equal).

The sorting also can be shortened to the construction like

```js
asArray.sort((a, b) => (a.points * 100 + a.netRuns) - (b.points * 100 + b.netRuns));
```

where constant we use to multiply should be greater than module of the max `b.netRuns`.

```js
const cricketMania = {
    India: {
        netRuns: "1.319",
        points: "8"
    },
    Pakistan: {
        netRuns: "1.028",
        points: "6"
    },
    Saudi: {
        netRuns: "0.874",
        points: "5"
    },
    Nepal: {
        netRuns: "-0.849",
        points: "4"
    },
    Bangladesh: {
        netRuns: "-1.176",
        points: "4"
    },
    Zimbabwe: {
        netRuns: "-1.138",
        points: "3"
    }
};

const asArray = Object.entries(cricketMania).map(([key, val]) => ({
    name: key,
    netRuns: +val.netRuns,
    points: +val.points
}));

asArray.sort((a, b) => a.points > b.points ? 1 :
                a.points < b.points ? -1 :
                a.netRuns > b.netRuns ? 1 : 
                a.netRuns < b.netRuns ? -1 : 0);
console.log(asArray);
```

Comment: Good job seeing past the problems with the OP and getting to what they're probably really trying to do. I believe the sort can be simplified to `(a, b) => a.points - b.points || a.netRuns - b.netRuns`, since equal points will yield a falsy 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of 3 JS functions, [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with compare function.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const cricketMania = {
  India: {
    netRuns: "1.319",
    points: "8"
  },
  Pakistan: {
    netRuns: "1.028",
    points: "6"
  },
  Saudi: {
    netRuns: "0.874",
    points: "5"
  },
  Nepal: {
    netRuns: "-0.849",
    points: "4"
  },
  Bangladesh: {
    netRuns: "-1.176",
    points: "4"
  },
  Zimbabwe: {
    netRuns: "-1.138",
    points: "3"
  }
};

const res = Object.values(cricketMania).map(({ points }) => points).sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(res);
```